# How can I prevent resizing of an Ogre3D object once imported into jMonkeyEngine?

Tags: blender, jmonkeyengine

I created an object in Blender: [image: http://oi42.tinypic.com/124y7vr.jpg]

Then I exported it as a *mesh.xml file* and attached it to the game scene: [image: http://oi42.tinypic.com/28s29gj.jpg] 
[Note: The gray color is the ground.]

In the game I end up with have a smaller, horizontal tower. Any suggestions?

Note: I exported the file with "Force Camera", "Force Lamps" and "Export Scene" unchecked and "Swap Axis: x,y,z".

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to apply your scale in blender first before exporting. Select the object (in your case the tower), press <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then select "Apply Rotation and Scale".

More info in the [Blender Wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Fade/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Reset_Object_Transformations).

Answer (score 0):

I don't export a lot of meshes, but this hasn't received much attention, and I figure I'd offer a fix at the very least.

You can change the size of Geometry objects with the scale() function and you can rotate them with setLocalRotation()

You can also change what the model considers up with rotateUpTo()

hopefully that helps.